# Sitecore User Group Jan 2019 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are super excited to announce the January'19 meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group!

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

Personalized Product Bundling in Sitecore Commerce 9 by Ishraq Al Fataftah - Sitecore MVP / CTO at Applez Tech

Interpreting Personalization and the Rule Set Editor by Jacqueline Baxter - 2018 Sitecore Strategy MVP | Digital Strategist at Hedgehog

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, Jan, 09, 2019 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, Jan, 09, 2019 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/257041200/) for more details and RSVP.

Comment: Done. Community promotion has begun.

Comment: Thank you @MarkCassidy